# multiprocessing.Process same speed as original for loop?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Suppose I have a function:

```
def support1(items, rows, output):
    n_rows = len(rows)
    if type(items) is list or type(items) is set:
        count = float(sum([1 for row in rows if all(item in row.split() for item in items)])) 
    elif type(items) is str:
        count = float(sum([1 for row in rows if all(item in row.split() for item in items.split())])) 
    res = count/n_rows
    output.put(res)
```

And I want to run this function over a list of 50,000 pairs of items, like the following:

```
all_items = [['apple', 'banana'], ['apple', 'fruit'],
            ['apple', 'pear'], ['banana', 'pear'], ...]
```

And I have 10,000 transactions to go through:

```
transactions = ['apple banana pear peach cream', 'apple banana pear', 'pear apple apple banana', 'pear banana', 'banana', 'apple', ...]
```

So, to count the frequencies of these pairs' occurring, I wrote something like this:

```
supports = [support1(pair, transactions, output) for pair in all_items]
```

This takes forever on my machine (obviously). I can't convert `transactions` to `set`. I'm trying to spin up some parallel processes, but it takes just as long for these to complete as for the `counts` assignment comprehension. Here's my parallel code:

```
import multiprocessing
output = mp.Queue()

processes = [multiprocessing.Process(target = support1, args = (pair, transactions, output)) for pair in all_items]

for p in processes:
    p.start()
```

The final `for` loop is what takes forever... Am I missing something with this `multiprocessing` module? I've done parallel processing before and it hasn't been this bad.

Comment: What you are doing now, is start a new process for every one of those 50,000 items. Multiprocessing can only speed things up when you have at most as many processes as you have cores.

Comment: How can I improve the code, then? Should I break up `all_items`, or maybe go with something else from the multiprocessing module, like `Pool`?

Comment: Yes, `Pool` would probably be a good direction,maybe `Pool.map`, but I'm afraid I cannot offer you a solution that I could guarantee to work.

Comment: I know where to go with `Pool.map`, but if you have a solution you'd like to try, feel free to leave it here. I'm developing my own now... I had never used `multiprocessing.Queue` before.